# getJSON remote refresh with keystrokes on input

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have this code, it runs/fires ONCE when the pages opens and returns a list in json format. what i can not figure out is how to make it fire again on a keypress/input. Can anyone help or advise how this can be done?

```
$("#vendorprovince").keypress(function(){
    var data = {};
        data.name = $("#vendorprovince").val(); 
        var url = 'ajax/get_provinces.php' + '?SearchVal=' + data.name;
         $.getJSON(url)
          .done(function (data) {
            $('#vendorprovince').typeahead(
            { 
            items: 10,
            source: data });

          });        

  });
```

Comment: I used firebug to see if any results are being returned that was not in the popup typeahead list. Data is being return, but the list not updated.

Comment: It seems that is working here http://jsfiddle.net/L8Lak/

Comment: it seems the .typeahead is not updating the list a second time. any idea how i can "clean" it every time time? I am using this: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead the documentation says to use $('.typeahead').typeahead('destroy') but i have no idea how to use it. Still learning javascript/jquery